# how to call function with multiple argument - postgresql 11

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions

I have function named `public.demoproc` below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.demoproc(i_schemaname character varying, i_objectname character varying, i_t_owner character varying) RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER
    AS $$
declare

v_statement text ;
begin

EXECUTE FORMAT('ALTER PROCEDURE %I.%I( owner to %I',i_schemaname,i_objectname,i_t_owner);


return FORMAT(' PROCEDURE "%I"."%I" Owner changed to "%I"',i_schemaname,i_objectname, i_t_owner );
END;
$$;
```

Now I want to call this proc like below with some arguments.

like function_name(argument1,argument2...)

```
select public.demoproc('schema_name', 'function_name', 'username');
```

When I run above command getting successful and if we have same function but different argument it's getting error.

Q:- Can you please help me how to add code for multiple arguments if function name is same (it may be integer,name etc) in above  public.demoproc code?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `select` to call the function (not a procedure!) is correct. What is the error you get?

Comment: syntax error i am getting near EXECUTE

Comment: HINT:  Specify the argument list to select the function unambiguously. I am getting this..

Comment: See here [Create Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) and the section `Overloading`. For `plpgsql` see [Polymorphic types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC)